# Right shift AND assignment operator logic?

Tags: java

Answer is 14 can anyone explain what's behind it?

```
int n = 7;
n<<=3;
n=n&n+1|n+2^n+3;
n>>=2;
System.out.print(n);
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's step through

```
int n = 7; //equals 0111

n<<=3;  //signed left shift 0111 3 spaces which equals 0111000

n=n&n+1|n+2^n+3; // (0111000 and 0111001) or (0111010 xor 0111011)
                 // 0111000 or 0000001
                 // 0111001

n>>=2;  //signed right shift 0111001 2 spaces equals 0001110 which equals 14
System.out.print(n);
```

In case you don't know,

`n<<=3` is equivalent to `n = n << 3`
similar to
`n += 1` is equivalent to `n = n + 1`

Comment: Thanks nicely explained

Answer (score 1):

Adding to NappaTheSaiyan's answer, shifts are equivalent to multiplication and division by base two.

So a left shift (i.e. n<<=3) is equivalent to multiplication, n*(2^3) or n*8.

Conversely, the right shift (i.e. n>>=2) is equivalent to division, n/(2^2) or n/4.

These are often used in place of multiplication/division since shifting requires less processing time, in terms of processor cycles, to compute than multiplication/division.